# Angular - Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular

This Angular Code doesn't let me display array . The error in console displays "Error trying to diff '[object Object]'"
My component.ts :

````
sprints : Sprint[] = [];

ngOnInit() : void {
    this.sprintService.getSprints().subscribe(
      data =>
      {
          console.log(data);
          this.sprints = data as any;
      }
    );
  }
```
this is html code :

```

<div *ngFor="let sprint of sprints">
    {{sprint.codeSprint}}
    {{sprint.title}}
  </div>
```

I got this error :
````

ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
at DefaultIterableDiffer.diff (core.js:26690)

```
When i logged I got the array but it deosn't diplay in html page
Thanks in advance !
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact data that you see in the logging? Also why do you use `data as any`? Why the `any`?

Comment: @Silvermind {code: 3, message: null, objet: Array(20)}
code: 3
message: null
objet: (20) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
__proto__: Object

Comment: Can't you just assign `data` to your `sprint` array? What's the purpose of using `data as any`?

Comment: sorry I forgot it there, because before i was using my sprints arrays like this : sprints : any[] = [];

Comment: So `data` is **not** an array, but `data.objet` is. Do you understand what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor` expects only iterable variables or arrays.

You can simply assign `data` to your `sprints` variable

```
......
data =>
  {
      console.log(data);
      this.sprints = data.objet;
  }
```

No need to use `data as any`.

If you want to use your `Sprint[]` model tho

```
....
(data: Sprint[]) => {
   this.sprints = data.objet;
}
```

Comment: I did like you said, but I still have the same error

Comment: what is the actual output of `data`?

Comment: like this : {code: 3, message: null, objet: Array(20)} but i want to display the array into table in html

Comment: so the array value is located at `data.objet`. I've updated my answer

Comment: i got this error : ERROR Property 'objet' does not exist on type 'Sprint[]'. even if I write my Sprint classe like this : export class Sprint {
  code : string;
  message : string;
  objet : Array<Object>;
  constructor() {
  }
}

Comment: How did you implement this on your `html`? Because if you want to directly assign your data value to `sprints` variable you don't have to add `data.objet` just assign `this.sprints = data;` instead

Comment: @Kirubel it does not matter if it is **typed** as `any`, as long as it is an array, which it is not. Your solution about `data.objet` is right though.

Comment: @Silvermind I thought `as any` will change the data type.

Comment: It will not. You only tell the typechecker that you know better and that the type is actually something else. You're not changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

that object having array of arrays

```
<div *ngFor="let sprint of sprints">
   <div *ngFor="let spr of sprint">
      {{spr.codeSprint}}
      {{spr.title}}
   </div>
  </div>
```

```
ngOnInit() : void {
    this.sprintService.getSprints().subscribe(
      data =>
      {
          console.log(data);
          this.sprints = data.object;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did as you said but I got this error : Property 'objet' does not exist on type 'Sprint[]'.

Comment: this is my Sprint Class: export class Sprint {
  code : string;
  message : string;
  objet : Array<Object>;
  constructor() {
  }
}

Comment: is this youe Sprint[]? 
{code: 3, message: null, objet: Array(20)} code: 3 message: null objet: (20) [Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4), Array(4)]
or show us the sample data you want to iterate

Comment: Yes, my Sprint class contains code(string), message(string) and objet de type Array<Object>